# chrome-remote-interface socket hang up

Tags: node.js, android-webview, adb, chrome-remote-debugging

I try to remote debug a WebView on android.

I already goth the process ID with this command `adb shell grep -a webview_devtools_remote /proc/net/unixc`

Then i made a port forwarding with this command `forward tcp:9483 localabstract:webview_devtools_remote_<The ID>`

When i access `http://localhost:9483` in my browser i get a link to `chrome://inspect` -> it is working

But when i try to connect with the `chrome-remote-interface` package i get a `stocket hang up` error

This is the code i tyred

```js
const CDP = require('chrome-remote-interface');

async function run() {
let client;
    try {
        client = await CDP({port:9483});
        const {Network, Page} = client;

        console.log("working")
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } finally {
        if (client) {
            await client.close();
        }
    }
}

await run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setting this option solves the problem `local: true`